# Screenshots of data in MS Excel

Tags: excel

How to take Screenshots of Data on Microsoft Excel?

This doc https://ccm.net/faq/9746-take-screenshots-of-data-on-microsoft-excel talks about option "As Picture" inside "Paste" but this option is not present.

Comment: Which excel version do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has changed from the earlier versions.

It should be **copy** in Excel 2016/2013/2010 (tested):

[image]

Then you will come to the next step where you can choose some options:

[image]

Comment: Glad to help :)!